# wxPython for Framework distribution rather than Conda

Tags: python, bash, wxpython

I've been struggling with getting wxPython work - I'm running a Mac, OSX 10.11.6 El Captain,  so the `pip` install runs into `/src/osx/cocoa/mediactrl.mm:52:10: fatal error: 'QTKit/QTKit.h' file not found`  with the new XCode, and some changes there, and won't compile. So I found an installer, that at least gets it done.

But then wx runs (I only tried to `import` it in fact) in my conda python 2.7.12.

My goal is to be able to play around with [TensorKart](https://github.com/kevinhughes27/TensorKart) and since my default python is conda, when attempting to run the repo, it tells me the usual:

```
This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are
logged in on the main display of your Mac.
```

I found how [George Reilly explains here](http://www.georgevreilly.com/blog/2015/09/20/RunSnakeRun-WxPython-Brew-Virtualenv.html) what to do, but I cannot find the `wxredirect.pth` and don't know what to do with the bash script. I only have `wx.pth` within the conda site-packages.

So **is it** somehow **possible** to get the `wxPython` for my Framework 2.7.10 with the .dmg installer? After 6 hours of struggle it seems like the easiest way.

I **tried**:

- copy conda site-packages having to do with wxPython into site-packages within a `virtualenv` created form the Framework Python as it was in the original G. Reilly's post which no longer works.
- create alias in .bash_profile that python is the Framework version but it didn't help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried this? `conda install -c anaconda wxpython=3.0.0.0` as in https://anaconda.org/anaconda/wxpython

Comment: @otterb yh I donwloaded it through anaconda before as well in the midst of attempts. I will try to reinstall this way, although  the version pip showed is the same

Comment: yh it seems to be the same. no change. still cannot find the wxredirect.pth. Is it somewhere in your installation?